# Get next / previous element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I get the next element in HTML using JavaScript?

Suppose I have three `<div>`s and I get a reference to one in JavaScript code, I want to get which is the next `<div>` and which is the previous.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well in pure javascript my thinking is that you would first have to collate them inside a collection.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
//divs now contain each and every div element on the page
var selectionDiv = document.getElementById("MySecondDiv");
```

So basically with selectionDiv iterate through the collection to find its index, and then obviously -1 = previous +1 = next within bounds

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length;i++)
{
   if(divs[i] == selectionDiv)
   {
     var previous = divs[i - 1];
     var next = divs[i + 1];
   }
}
```

Please be aware though as I say that extra logic would be required to check that you are within the bounds i.e. you are not at the end or start of the collection.

This also will mean that say you have a div which has a child div nested.  The next div would not be a sibling but a child, So if you only want siblings on the same level as the target div then definately use nextSibling checking the **tagName** property.

Comment: seams good solution but how to get the next element, as you wrote now i have the collection and the selected one, can you help me more?

Answer (score 331):

use the [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) properties:

```
<div id="foo1"></div>
<div id="foo2"></div>
<div id="foo3"></div>

document.getElementById('foo2').nextSibling; // #foo3
document.getElementById('foo2').previousSibling; // #foo1
```

However in some browsers (I forget which) you also need to check for whitespace and comment nodes:

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo2');
var nextSibling = div.nextSibling;
while(nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType != 1) {
    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling
}
```

Libraries like jQuery handle all these cross-browser checks for you out of the box.

Comment: nextSibling and previousSibling (should) always return all nodes, not just element nodes shouldn't they?  This includes text nodes, comment nodes, etc.  Your second example looks like a good solution for this!  Maybe you could cut down on the repetition with a do {} while(); loop?  (edit: or recursion perhaps)

Comment: BE aware that the "sibling" is the next element in the same level of the tree. And HTML stipulates some automatic elements closing than can bit you. For example `<p>bla <a id='foo1'></a><div id='foo2'>` . Here, the DIV closes the previously opened P element, so 'foo1' has no next sibling.

Comment: nextElementSibling is much more useful.

Comment: Note that neither nextSibling nor nextElementSibling are fully cross browser compatible. Firefox's nextSibling returns text nodes while IE doesn't and nextElementsibling is not implemented until IE9.

Comment: This will not work if the elements are not siblings.

Comment: @Kloar: The question asked how to get the "next [div] element in html." The next `div` in the markup might not be adjacent to the element; it might be a level deeper or a level higher.

Comment: Don't forget to add ';' inside the while loop statement.

Comment: @Dementic Not really. My example with autoclosing `<p>` is "clean and valid html". And Javascript does not "act strange" here. My warning is directed towards some programmers who think HTML (and its DOM) in terms of XML (which it isn't). If you understand that in my example the DIV is a sibling of the P element, not of the A element, then it's all right.

Comment: @rvighne One hopes it would be obvious that a property called "next*Sibling*" would necessitate elements being siblings.

Answer (score 39):

Its quite simple. Try this instead:

```
let myReferenceDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
let prev = myReferenceDiv.previousElementSibling;
let next = myReferenceDiv.nextElementSibling;
```

Answer (score 34):

Really depends on the overall structure of your document.

If you have:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

it may be as simple as traversing through using

```
mydiv.nextSibling;
mydiv.previousSibling;
```

However, if the 'next' div could be anywhere in the document you'll need a more complex solution. You could try something using

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

and running through these to get where you want somehow.

If you are doing lots of complex DOM traversing such as this I would recommend looking into a library such as jQuery.

Comment: nextSibling() .. should be nextSibling, I think

Answer (score 27):

There is a attribute on every HTMLElement, "previousElementSibling".

Ex:

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">c</div>

<div id="result">Resultado: </div>
```

---

```
var b = document.getElementById("c").previousElementSibling;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += b.innerHTML;
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/QukKM/

Comment: This fails on IE8 (haven't checked on other IE versions). `previousSibling` seems to be the cross browser solution.

Answer (score 17):

This will be easy...
its an pure javascript code

```
    <script>
           alert(document.getElementById("someElement").previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 9):

all these solutions look like an overkill.
Why use my solution?

`previousElementSibling` supported from IE9

`document.addEventListener` needs a polyfill

`previousSibling` might return a text

Please note i have chosen to return the first/last element in case boundaries are broken.
In a RL usage, i would prefer it to return a null.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("child1"),
    children = el.parentNode.children,
    len = children.length,
    ind = [].indexOf.call(children, el),
    nextEl = children[ind === len ? len : ind + 1],
    prevEl = children[ind === 0 ? 0 : ind - 1];
    
    document.write(nextEl.id);
    document.write("<br/>");
    document.write(prevEl.id);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use **nextElementSibling** or **previousElementSibling** properties

```
<div>
    <span id="elem-1">
        span
    </span>
</div>
<div data-id="15">
    Parent Sibling
</div>


const sp = document.querySelector('#elem-1');
let sibling_data_id = sp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.dataset.id;
console.log(sibling_data_id); // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested it and it worked for me. The element finding me change as per the document structure that you have.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id = "formId" action="action.php" onsubmit="return false;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="standard_text">E-mail</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input class="textarea"  name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail"></label></td>
                    <td><input class="textarea"  name="name" id="name" placeholder="E-mail">   </label></td>
                    <td><input class="textarea"  name="myname" id="myname" placeholder="E-mail"></label></td>
                    <td><div class="check_icon icon_yes" style="display:none" id="mail_ok_icon"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="check_icon icon_no" style="display:none" id="mail_no_icon"></div></label></td>
                    <td><div class="check_message" style="display:none" id="mail_message"><label class="important_text">The email format is not correct!</label></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="button_submit" type="submit" name="send_form" value="Register"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var inputs;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var form = document.getElementById('formId');
    inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length;i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                var currentIndex = findElement(e.target)
                if(currentIndex > -1 && currentIndex < inputs.length) {
                    inputs[currentIndex+1].focus();
                }
            }   
        });
    }
});

function findElement(element) {
    var index = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i] == element) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

that's so simple

```
var element = querySelector("div")
var nextelement = element.parentElement.querySelector("div+div")
```

Here is the browser supports https://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: Should be `element.parentElement`, `ParentElement` doesn't seem to work.