# file upload button without input field?

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery : simulating a click on a <input type=“file” /> doesn't work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Is it possible to have a file button without an input beside it by default?  Ideally all I want is a button that lets the user navigate to a file without showing what they selected prior to an upload.  I'll submit the form by the following after a user chooses a file:

```
$("#file").change(function() {
    $("#update_button").trigger('click');
});
```

I'm sure this must be possible with some css or jquery magic...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I remember correctly, HTML5 allows you to call the `click` method on a hidden input element to show the file dialog via a custom button (why not just make it work without an element, I don't know). Unfortunately not all currently in use browsers support this yet, so you're stuck with styling a file input to look like a button.

This is a hilariously ugly but ingenious CSS hack I came across on a site once (probably imgur):

```
.fileupload {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: ...; /* and other things to make it pretty */
}

.fileupload input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; /* not left, because only the right part of the input seems to
                 be clickable in some browser I can't remember */
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* and all the other old opacity stuff you
                                 want to support */
    font-size: 300px; /* wtf, but apparently the most reliable way to make
                         a large part of the input clickable in most browsers */
    height: 200px;
}
```

And the HTML to go with it:

```
<div class="fileupload">
  <input type="file" />
  Any content here, perhaps button text
</div>
```

What it does is it makes the file input itself enormous (by changing the font size (!?)) to ensure it covers the button, and then cuts off the excess with `overflow: hidden;`. This may not work for absolutely enormous buttons.

Comment: This is useless, as in some browsers the filename comes before the button, while in others it comes after. See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/pix/filefields.gif

Comment: @Dbugger: IIRC Safari allows you to click the text part as well, as do a lot of other browsers. At least IE doesn't like clicks on the field, hence the right positioning. I checked, and it's infact what imgur.com does, and I'm pretty sure they're a pretty good field test.

Comment: It seems that most of these examples work with the exception of older browser...meaning IE 8 and below

Comment: @Paul: We've tested this thing on IE 6 and up. That old enough for you?

Comment: That should work...I was using IE Tester and it wasn't working on IE 7 and 8 but that could be IE Tester I suppose

Comment: does not work in firefox (

Comment: @ProstoTrader: Got a jsfiddle of it not working?

Answer (score 57):

You could simply hide the `input` button with `visibility: hidden;`, and attach a click event handler to the other button:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="somename" size="chars">
<button>Choose File</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input').click();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCzuh/

Comment: This seems to work great on Chrome and IE 9 but nothing older :(

Comment: @Paul - Interesting. I don't have any older versions of IE installed, but I tested it by changing the browser mode to IE7, and it worked!?!

Comment: Interesting...maybe IE Tester isn't working correctly (I wouldn't be suprised) I'll try the same here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you set the opacity to 0, then you can add another div underneath it that looks like a button. You can style this any way you like then.

Working code example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fakeuploadbutton">upload</div>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery('#file').css('opacity',0);    
</script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .wrapper { position: relative; }
    .fakeuploadbutton { 
        background: red url('myuploadbutton.png') no-repeat top left;
        width: 100px; height: 30px;
    }
    #file { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px; left: 0px; 
        width: 100px; height: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the best approach for cross browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

An option to look at is here:

http://shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

This allows for more customization of an `<input>` field