# document Uploader with react in form?

Tags: reactjs

Help me please to find a realization of file loader in react without drag-n-drop.

I have a form with a block. This block has a link. When I click this link, the window of file loader should appeared.

Also I can delete the file after loading.

Without any plugins.

Comment: I have a span or link and I want to open a window when I can choose a file, not input button with type 'file'

Comment: `not input button with type 'file'` && `Without any plugins.` = No

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350927/file-upload-button-without-input-field