# Can't capture onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a solution where you hide the file chosen by a user for an input type of 'file'.  Here is the stack article that outlines the solution:  [input type=file show only button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button)

I am not able to capture the onChange event, and hence am unable to read the file.  The event in the method 'saveFileToStoreOnChange' is undefined. Where did I go off the road here?

html (jsx):

```
<input className="invisible" type="file" id="logo"/>
<input type="button" value="Browse..." onClick={this.saveFileToStoreClick} />
```

Javascript:

```
saveFileToStoreClick(){
        $('#logo').on('change', this.saveFileToStoreOnChange());
    }

saveFileToStoreOnChange(event){
        //event is undefined
        let file = event.target.files[0];
}
```

Comment: You're *calling* `this.saveFileToStoreOnChange()` instead of *passing* it to `on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the correct context in the event. Bind or use an arrow function:

```
onClick={(e) => this.saveFileToStoreClick(e)}
```

I don't know why you're binding to the event with jQuery programmatically though (or even using jQuery, or an ID selector instead of a reference). I didn't understand the reason for not having an `onChange` handler on the file input.

As a commenter said you're also calling the function instead of passing it in your event.

Comment: The reason I dont have an onChange handler on the file input can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button.   It's the second solution I am trying to implement where the file selected is hidden.

Comment: the correct solution to this problem is to not use jQuery with React...

Comment: Agreed.  and - I found the solution to the problem by using a simple .css class as found with the second solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105116/anyway-to-remove-no-file-selected-from-type-file-inputs

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `this.saveFileToStoreOnChange()` instead of passing the function.

Change your code to:

```js
$('#logo').on('change', this.saveFileToStoreOnChange);
```

(See the removed `()` after the function name)

Comment: Didn't work.  It never made it to the saveFileToStoreOnChange method

Answer (score 0):

This code may helps you

```
saveFileToStoreClick(){

            $('#logo').on('change', this.saveFileToStoreOnChange());
        }

    saveFileToStoreOnChange(event){


            let file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
    }
```