# Input TYPE="File" hide the input and leave the button?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to hide the input in a `input type="file"` and leave the button?

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [input type=file show only button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the file input has been a thorn in the side of HTML styling.  There are some workarounds for it, however.  Take a look at [a jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/custom-file) which obscures the input with some custom elements.  Styling and customizing those elements is much easier.

[This](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/) is a good article on the subject as well.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. Here are [some techniques](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) to style this field which hide the original field and replace it with some standard input which is then using javascript to reflect the original.

Answer (score 1):

Use the clip property. Absolute positioning is required, so add a relatively positioned container.

```
input[type="file"] { outline: none; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top:0; clip: rect(0px 222px 22px 145px);  }
```

Webkit browsers require different coordinates:

```
* > /**/ input[type="file"], x:-webkit-any-link { outline: none; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top:0; clip: rect(0px 86px 22px 0px);  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn-upload').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#file').click();
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #file { display:none; } 
</style>

<div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button type="button" id="btn-upload">Image</button>
</div>
```