# Change the label in an HTML file input

Tags: html

Does anyone if the label of an `<input type="file">` can be hidden? I can't find anything useful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "label"?

Comment: On some browsers there's a label beside the button used to select the file that will be uploaded.

Comment: Are you talking about "Browse"?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button

Comment: @Justin: I think that's a little presumptuous. He said "labels", not "input box".

Comment: That post refers to the text box that is beside the button. I'm talking about the label that says "No file chosen". Here's a screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/screenshot20120201at124.png/

Answer (score 4):

Make the color the same as the background, for example:

```
html, input, textarea {
color: #something or other;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! `<input id="post_thumbnail" name="post[thumbnail]" style="color: white;" type="file">` Much simpler than the duplicate.