# Get button part of file input element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file-io

I have a file input element as in code below. How would I get the button part of this file input control using jQuery?

```
<input type="file" name="FILE1" id="FILE1"></input>
```

Comment: You can't, take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337629/how-to-change-input-type-file-design-so-it-wont-display-the-text-field/11337696#11337696)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input) has nice answers/hacks

Comment: @elclanrs - Thanks for the help. Its a nice approach to styling file input control with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not possible because file input behavior is under control of the browser and manipulating that causes security-related issues like preventing the file-upload. however you can set the opacity of `file input` to `0`, and create a dummy element instead and trigger the `click` event for file input by clicking that:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("input[type='file']").trigger("click");        
})
```

Comment: I dont think its possible to trigger `click` cross browser (security reasons). Also, changing opacity to 0 shouldnt affect its `clicking` ability.

Comment: @Jashwant i have used this method for my website and it works in all browsers, but instead of `input[type='file']` an `id` can prevent security problems.

Comment: `click` is actually the only event that works across browsers. `change` on the other hand has some problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The button part is browser specific.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of questions and answers on this that cover what you *can* do with a file input. It's not much, but it is something.

[Style input type file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file)

Erick