# Rails bootstrap form file upload button not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and rails 4. I want to remove the white input field line under Avatar and only display my file upload button!

This is what it looks like: 
[image]

This is my edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
<div class="well bs-component">
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
  <div>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>
<%= f.label 'Add an image' %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my html output:

```
<h2>Edit User</h2>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="edit_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden"><input name="_method" value="put" type="hidden"><input name="authenticity_token" value="vpVmH4k1YDXgJxAiZtVoI872hR67COFNoo1irki8sAY=" type="hidden"></div>

<img alt="Justdoit" src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/justdoit.png?1393323443">
  <div>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_email">Email</label><input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user[email]" value="ggeorgiev@live.co.uk" type="email"></div></div>


  <div> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_password">Password</label><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password"></div></div>

  <div><br>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><input class="form-control" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" type="password"></div></div>

  <div><i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_current_password">Current password</label><input class="form-control" id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" type="password"></div></div>
<label for="user_Add an image">Add an image</label>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_avatar">Avatar</label><input class="form-control" id="user_avatar" name="user[avatar]" type="file"></div>

  <div><input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" value="Update" type="submit"></div>
</form>
<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? </p><form action="/users" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" value="Cancel my account" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="vpVmH4k1YDXgJxAiZtVoI872hR67COFNoo1irki8sAY=" type="hidden"></div></form><p></p>

<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling the HTML input elements is not something browsers support currently [input type=file show only button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button)

We recently used [jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to style this type of button ([site](http://video-conference-demo.herokuapp.com)):

[image]

This basically works by replacing the default button with a simple CSS-based one. The code we used is here:

```
 .items .avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    width: 260px;
 }
 .items .avatar .avatar img     { display: block; }
 .items .avatar .avatar         { position: relative; }
 .items .avatar .avatar:after   {
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 160px 0 0 107px;
    content: url('profile/new_avatar.png');
    background: url('profile/photo_delete_bg.png');
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
 }
 .items .avatar .avatar input { z-index: 999; height: 100%;}
 .items .avatar .avatar:hover:after   { opacity: 0.8; }
 .items .avatar .avatar:active:after  { opacity: 0.6; }
```

---

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="avatar">        
     <!-- New Avatar Upload Form -->
     <%= form_for :upload, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => "avatar"}, :method => :put, url: profile_path(current_user.id), "data_id" => current_user.id do |f| %>
         <div class="btn btn-success fileinput-button avatar" id="avatar_container">
             <%= f.file_field :avatar, :title => "Upload New" %>
             <%= image_tag(@user.profile.avatar.url, :width=> '100%', :id => "avatar_img", :alt => name?(@user)) %>
         </div>
     <% end %>
            <div class="name"><%= link_to name?(@user), root_path %></div> 
    </div>
```

---

There is a much better setup on this question (I copied directly from it for you):

> You can try a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VQJ9V/307/
>   (Tested in FF 7, IE 9, Safari 5, Opera 11 and Chrome 14)
>
> It works by creating a big file input (with font-size:50px), then
>   wrapping it in a div that has a fixed size and overflow:hidden. The
>   input is then only visible through this "window" div. The div can be
>   given a background image or color, text can be added, and the input
>   can be made transparent to reveal the div background:

```
HTML:

<div class="inputWrapper">
    <input class="fileInput" type="file" name="file1"/> </div> CSS:

.inputWrapper {
    height: 32px;
    width: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*Using a background color, but you can use a background image to represent a button*/
    background-color: #DDF; } .fileInput {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    /*This makes the button huge. If you want a bigger button, increase the font size*/
    font-size:50px;
    /*Opacity settings for all browsers*/
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0) }
```

Comment: All done - bit of a mish-mash, but should guide you in the right direction