# How to use file uploader in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanted to make use of a file uploader that will open a file dialog box and when I will select a file, its location will be shown in a different textbox. I made the use of the below code in my View to display the file dialog. However, I am not able to display the location of the file that is chosan from the file dialog on a different textbox as the below code already have a pre defined label by the name "your text here" which displays the chosan file name after selection. How will I be able to display the location onto a different textbox and how should I be able to delete that predefined label appearing? Any help will be appreciated

```
<input type="file" id="upload"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for get full path of your selected file

```
<input id="myFileUpload" type="file"/>
<input id="textbox" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myFileUpload').change(function () {
            $("#textbox").val($('#myFileUpload').val())
        });
    });
</script>
```

and read following article to hide built in lable in file uploader
[Hide lable in file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried the above code but this displays wrong path under the textbox, something like c:\fakepath\filename.exe"

Comment: Hi, browser not allow you to do that, for security reason

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack wrote a post on this subject, [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do not waste your time on this it's not possible.

Read this: [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Try like this, but it's not display path value on text box,

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);
});
```