# Make button disabled if input type file is empty in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have form where the user can upload a file but I want the upload button to be disabled if the input type file does not contain a file how do I do that ?

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="fileUploaded">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Upload file</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add attribute disabled to the button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" disabled>Upload file</button>
```

then we will watch changes with the code to enable the button when the input type file contain any file

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    if($('input[type=file]').val()==''){
        $('button').attr('disabled',true)
    } 
    else{
      $('button').attr('disabled',false);
    }
})
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/08eekkbt/

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button)

I like this solution from the linked post:

```html
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
<input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
```