# Can't change the side text from type"file" input

Tags: html, forms, input, types, form-control

I'm doing a form and i can't change the side text that appears with the type="file" input.

[This Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQVM.jpg)

Thats my code.

```html
    <div class="form-group text-left">
   <label style="margin-left:16px">CPF*</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
     <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i></span>
      <input  name="cpf" placeholder="Informe seu CPF" class="form-control" id="cpf" required="required">
            <input id="arquivo_cpf" type="file" name="arquivo_cpf" required="required" >
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can help you.

You can put label inside a  using bootstrap, then you can use "display: none;" at the input.
Then, you can write what you want, making it smaller.

See the code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group text-left">
   <label style="margin-left:16px">CPF*</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
     <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i></span>
      <input  name="cpf" placeholder="Informe seu CPF" class="form-control" id="cpf" required="required">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><label class="btn btn-default btn-file ">
              Choose file<input type="file" id="arquivo_cpf" name="arquivo_cpf" style="display:none" required="require">
    </label></span>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="input-group-btn"><label class="btn btn-default btn-file ">
              Choose File<input type="file" id="arquivo_cpf" name="arquivo_cpf" style="display:none" required="require">
    </label></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-browser way to do this. The "no file selected" text is in the implementation-defined part of the widget, and I don't believe that most browsers offer much in the way of browser-specific customization. On the other hand, you could simply use CSS to cover the text with something when the value attribute is empty.

```
input[type='file'] {
color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. This helps to hide the text, but really wanted to change the text to something smaller.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084925/input-type-file-show-only-button/7691323#7691323