# how to apply css rule to the previous and the next element in HTML?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser, stylesheet

For example:

You have this:

```
<ul>
 <li>zero</li>
 <li>one</li>
 <li class="selected">two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>more elements</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.selected:previous {
   color: red;
}

.selected:next {
   color: green;
}
```

That's possible?

Comment: Don't think a CSS only solution is available but a *pure* JavaScript option would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/3597276

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not possible with pure css. You can style next but not previous element.

But you can do a trick with css. Instead of give class **selected** you can give  class to your **previous** element. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li>zero</li>
 <li class="previous">one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>more elements</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.previous{
   color: green;
}
.previous + li{
   color: red;
}
.previous + li + li{
    color:yellow;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/S5kUM/2/

Answer (score 6):

It's called sibling selector:

```
.selected + li {
   color: red;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pXMwa/)

However, there is no sibling selector for the previous element.
​

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be done with JavaScript.

If you are using jQuery, it can be done like this:

```
$('.selected').prev().css('color', 'red');
$('.selected').next().css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: `how to apply css rule` implies OP wants CSS answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to reverse the list.

http://codepen.io/bscherer/pen/XMgpbb