# Native JavaScript alternative for jQuery's next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$.each(this.items, function(key, item) {
    item = $(item);
    item.css('background', 'red');
    item.next().css('display', 'none');
}
```

Now, I need to rewrite it in pure JavaScript so I am doing this

```
document.getElementById(aItems[iCount].id).style.background = 'red';
document.getElementById(aItems[iCount].id).style.display = 'none';
```

The problem is that `display:none` must be set for the `next()` item, not this one, how do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get next/previous element using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
item.nextSibling.style.display = 'none'
```

Keep in mind that [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling) [might select the text content next to the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling#Example), so you may need to use:

```
item.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = 'none'
```

---

Another option would be to use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling), as Bergi suggested. However, that's not supported in all browsers, yet. You can create the function yourself, though:

```
function nextElementSibling(element) {
    do { 
        element = element.nextSibling;
    } while (element && element.nodeType !== 1);
    return element;
}
```

In this case:

```
nextElementSibling(item).style.display = 'none';
```

---

Last but not least, I'd suggest having a look at [Palash' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14198040/1835379) if you want to replace jQuery's `$.each()` with native JS.

Comment: Note that this will take all node types into account, so you may get unexpected results if there is a text node (or a comment, or some other non-element node) right after the first element. `nextElementSibling` is the right tool for the job, but unfortunately isn't supported everywhere.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Added an alternative.

Comment: Would the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a msitake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`nextElementSibling` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) of the selected DOM node:

```
var item = document.getElementById(aItems[iCount].id);
item.style.background = 'red';
item.style.display = 'none';
if (item.nextElementSibling)
    item.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
for(var iCount = 0; iCount < aItems.length;i++)
{
     var current = aItems[iCount].id;
     var next = aItems[iCount + 1].id;
     if ( next != null ) {
          document.getElementById(current).style.background = 'red';
          document.getElementById(next).style.display = 'none';
     }
}
```