# How to get the next cell in a TableView of UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

In UIAutomation is there something similar to sibling in DOM - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling or next in jQuery -  http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next

After I get a cell, I want the cell immediately before or after it. For example in the following

[image]

Assuming I already have a reference to Cell named 12:00 pm. How can I get cells above and below it?

I think I can make this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/574914/31252 work but I am wondering if there is something I can do better.

Answer (score 0):

No, alas this isn't much like the document object model. Elements don't know anything about their siblings or how to traverse the tree. You'll have to construct your own data structure to keep track of this information.