# previousSibling not working

Tags: javascript

I want to target the first `<p>` inside the div by selecting the second `<p>` and using `previousSibling` property but it is not working.

```
<div id="par">
<p id="p1">test</p>
<p id="p2">test</p>
</div>


document.getElementById('p2').previousSibling.className = 'red';
```

**EDIT:**

OK it works on all browsers except IE8 but I want it to work in IE8 as well, I tried the following conditional but to no effect:

```
var c = document.getElementById('p2').previousElementSibling.className = 'red';

if (c == undefined) {

    c = document.getElementById('p2').previousSibling.className = 'red';
}
```

It still works everywhere but IE8. How can I change the above conditional for IE8?

**EDIT 2:**

Managed to get it to work in IE8 as well:

```
var c = document.getElementById('p2');

if (c.previousElementSibling) {

    c.previousElementSibling.className = 'red';

} else {

    c.previousSibling.className = 'red';

}
```

Comment: There's an empty text node between the elements.

Comment: Thanks. I used previousSibling twice and it worked. Will this work for all browsers?

Comment: Most likely, though you should use `previousElementSibling` as in Dogbert's answer. If you're concerned with older browsers, you can use [this fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/574922/1331430) (you will have to replace `nextSibling` calls with `previousSibling`)

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.previousElementSibling) to get the previous Element node.

```
document.getElementById('p2').previousElementSibling.className = 'red';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6Bh8/

Note: This does not work on IE <= 8 according to MDN link above. You would probably need to loop through `previousSibling` until you find an Element node.

Comment: @dzumla011, the solution linked by Fabricio in the comments on the question should work well in all cases (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript/574922#574922).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be the simplest way:

```
var p=document.getElementById('p2');
do {
    p=p.previousSibling;
}while(p && p.tagName!='P');
p.className='red';
```

Comment: It would probably be better, in the `while` condition, to test for `(p && p.nodeType != 1)`. You should ensure that there is a `previousSibling`. All nodes have a `nodeType` but only HTML elements have a `nodeType` of 1. Not an issue in this particular example but suppose the HTML changes and the previous element is not a `<p>`