# Get JavaScript components top-down

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a DOM and whenever I want to find an element I don't want to do getElementByID/Class all the time. I want the ability to get the 1st element and then from that position get elements 1 by 1 moving down. I.e

```
<div>
  <p id="1"></p>
  <p id="2"></p>
  <p id="3"></p>
</div>
```

Assuming I want "1","2" and "3" one after the other, I want the ability to get 1 and then from there on move down to get 2 and then from there get 3. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you look at the DOM APIs (`children`)?

Comment: `getElementById` is only defined on `document`. However, `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector`, and `querySelectorAll` work on any element, allowing you to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
document.getElementById('1').nextSibling;
```

Also, check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/574922

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to walk the tree. In your case,

```
const first = document.getElementById('1');
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(first, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
let next;

while (next = walker.nextSibling()) {
  console.log("Got next sibling", next);
}
```

If all you want is to get siblings, this may be overkill, but it provides the ability to do more complex types of walking.

You can also consider using [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), which allows you to find nodes based on the language called XPath. In this case, it would look something like

```
const xPathResult = document.evaluate('following-sibling::p', first, 
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

This will return an iterator you can walk through:

```
while (next = xPathResult.iterateNext()) {
  console.log("Got next sibling", next);
}
```

This could be useful if your conditions for choosing elements are more complex, since XPath can represent virtually anything.

Another way to grab elements, of course, is `querySelectorAll`. However, it offers no way to select siblings. You will need to start with the parent:

```
first.parentNode.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Of course, that will give you all descendants, not just direct children. To get the second and following siblings:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#1 > p:not(:first-child)')
```