# Distribute the out but into the <inputs> throw loops by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to update the `<input>` attribute when changing the `<select>` one:

/// HTML Code ///

```
<select name="Pending_status" id="Type" class="Type" onChange="moveas();">
<option value="Internal Movement" id="Internal_Movement">Internal Movement</option>
<option value="Resignation" id="Resignation">Resignation</option>
<option value="Termination" id="Termination">Termination</option>
</select>


<div class="Check" id="Check">

</div>
```

/// Java script Code ///

```
    function moveas() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Type");
    var type = '';
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        type += elements[i].value+"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("Check").innerHTML = type+"<br>";
   };
```

[But as the pic shows I get the results on the first row only, i don't know how to distribute them on each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DneKf.jpg)

I tried using the document.getElementsByClassName("Check") but it gives me nothing. so can you help?

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same ID in the same document in HTML. So if you have multiple rows with the HTML you show there, you're going to have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Never use the same ID twice!

Essentially, the problem is that you insert several lines, but you want to manipulate the innerHTML of several different HTML-tags. What you do is:

```
<div class="Check" id="Check">
    content<br>
    morecontent<br>
</div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div class="Check" id="Check1">
    content
</div>
<div class="Check" id="Check2">
    morecontent
</div>
```

see the difference?

It appears there is some HTML-code missing. I guess you are using a `<table>`-like structure. (columns are elements of rows.) In that case, an easy solution would be to use [javascript siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript). Otherwise, you would have to access the elements through some kind of global identifier. E.g.: I gave them different ids in my example, so you could retrieve them using getElementById:

```
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("Check"+i).innerHTML=elements[i].value;
}
```