# Pure javascript alternative for jQuery .prev()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(".q-block-container").prev(".sub-block-container").css("border-bottom","none");
```

I need a pure JavaScript equivalent, whereby I can select the previous sibling **ONLY** if it matches the selector (in this case `.sub-block-container`).

For example, lets say I have a list and each item in the list has a `border-bottom` style. Depending in what the sibling is before a particular list item, that should determine whether or not the border should be applied:

```
<ul>
    <li class="q"></li>
    <li class="q"></li>
    <li class="q"></li>
    <li class="s"></li>
    <li class="s"></li>
    <li class="q"></li>
    <li class="s"></li>
    <li class="q"></li>
</ul>
```

In this example, a border must NOT appear on the previous sibling `<li>` element if:

- the element is q and the previous sibling is s
- the element is s and the previous sibling is q
- the element is s and the previous sibling is s

Comment: May I ask why? This doesn't seem like an efficient thing to do.

Comment: What's the efficient thing to do?

Comment: I have taken a look at your example. In this case, I assume your rows are programmatically generated. What is usually done is to assign classes directly to the elements that you wish to have certain property, ie in this case you would add a class `with-border` to elements that should have a border *before* they are put into the DOM.

Comment: Sure, but list items are added ad-hoc by the user and they can also reorder them, so the list needs to re-update the borders each time a change happens.

Comment: I'm sure you have an internal object representing the rows. You should perform checks on the internal objects instead of checking the DOM. Interacting with the DOM and matching CSS selectors are quite expensive operations.

Comment: Right, I see your point. The list a React component and the list items are seperate React components. The structure of the list is stored in Redux, so I could go through this and add a class depending on the prev/next sibling.

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript

Comment: @JoeTidee Since you are using React, I suppose it should be even simpler. You just have to update your state and trigger a re-render.

Comment: The logic may be easier if the decision to apply a border is based on comparing the content of an element with that of its _next sibling_.

Comment: Please provide your current code and possibly some kind of visual representation of desired outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this if your element `.sub-block-container` will have only that single class.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("q-block-container");
for (i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
    var prev = elem[i].previousElementSibling;
    if (prev.className == "sub-block-container") {
        prev.style.borderBottom = "none";
    }
}
```

If your element may have more than one class, use this instead:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("q-block-container");
for (i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
    var prev = elem[i].previousElementSibling;
    if (prev.classList.contains("sub-block-container")) {
        prev.style.borderBottom = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also use `if(prev.classList.contains("sub-block-container")){...}` for IE >= 10

Comment: should be `previousElementSibling` or it will crash with textNodes.

Comment: @JoeTidee yes that's right. I was not aware of that property

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = 
        Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
        function(s) {
            var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
            return i > -1;            
        };
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.q-block-container');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var previous = element.previousElementSibling;
    if(previous.matches('.sub-block-container')){
        previous.style.borderBottom = 'none';
    }
}​
```

So it is quite straightforward, you iterate over all the .q-block-container and if one's previous sibling matches the .sub-block-container selector, it changes its border-bottom

Edit :

Thank you Abraham Murciano Benzadon for pointing out an error in the code (semi-colons aren't required in JS tho, but it's best to keep the same code style)

Edit 2 :

Fixed the code to what you want