# How to find out prev() of first child in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have four count class in div tag.

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <div class="count active">total</div>
    <div class="count ">addition</div>
    <div class="count ">substraction</div>
    <div class="count ">multiplication</div>
    <div class="count ">division</div>
</div>
```

**What I want** : find out prev child , make prev child active.
**Question** : How to find prev() of `<div class="count active">total</div>` ?

Comment: if they are siblings, you can use [element.previousElementSibling](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling.html)

Comment: jQuery or plain JavaScript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript

Comment: You can also look at `HtmlElement.parent`

Comment: Your question makes very little sense, plus it appears as if you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a sloution

```
                        var count = $(container).find('.count');
                        var active = $(container).find('.active');
                        var prev = active.prev('.count');
                        active.removeClass("active");
                        if (prev.length === 0) {
                            prev = count.last('.count');
                        }
                        prev.addClass("active");
                        var filter = prev.data('filter');
```