# How to copy option element after a specific option value element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I copy the select option element after a specific option value in JavaScript/jQuery?

**Here's my two selects**

First select where I want to copy the option below the copy value

```
<select class="select">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="copy">Copy below</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Second select where I want to append what I copy on first element

```
<select class="select">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?  Selecting the first `select`?  Selecting the `option`(s) to copy?  Appending them to the 2nd `select`?

Comment: I don't know how should I copy the option below `copy` value only and not the whole select element. the appending is okay with me.

Comment: Select the "copy" option, then use `nextElementSibling` to get the next `option` elements until you run out. See [Get next / previous element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574904/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the option element with attribute equal selector, along with `.nextAll()`, `.clone()`  and `.appendTo()` to create clone of option element and append in second select dropdown

```
$('option[value=copy]').nextAll().clone().appendTo('.select2');
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('option[value=copy]').nextAll().clone().appendTo('.select2');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="copy">Copy below</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First select the first element to copy :

```
let $copyElement = $('#firstSelect option[value="copy"]').next();
```

Then, while elements are available, clone them and append them to the second select:

```
while($copyElement.length > 0) {
  $('#secondSelect').append( $copyElement.clone() );
  $copyElement = $copyElement.next();
}
```

```js
let $copyElement = $('#firstSelect option[value="copy"]').next();
while($copyElement.length > 0) {
 $('#secondSelect').append( $copyElement.clone() );
  $copyElement = $copyElement.next();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" id="firstSelect">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="copy">Copy below</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select class="select" id="secondSelect">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function copyOpts(a, b) {
    if ($("option:selected", a).val() == "copy") {
      $("option:selected", a).nextAll().clone().appendTo(b);
    }
  }

  $(".primary").change(function() {
    copyOpts($(".primary"), $(".secondary"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select primary">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="copy">Copy below</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select class="select secondary">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

You can move the `if()` statement to either the `change` callback, or leave it in the function.

See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/
- https://api.jquery.com/clone/
- https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/