# How to select sibling div based on button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a form, I have a parent class "UPD" and under this div element I have two elements a button `"class="collapsible"` and a div `class="ui-form-element section-row sections"` I want to select sibling div `class="ui-form-element section-row sections"`
not based on the class but as sibling div using javascript.

```
<div class="UPD">
   <button class="collapsible">button</button>
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row sections" id="uid-3-sections" style="display: none;">
   </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: See [Element.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling). Also see [Get next / previous element using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574922/924299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for,

```js
let current = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
let nextSibling = current.nextElementSibling;
console.log(nextSibling);
```

```html
<div class="UPD">
   <button class="collapsible">button</button>
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row sections" id="uid-3-sections" style="display: none;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select `nextSibling` using `this` keyword and can display it when `button` is clicked

```js
function lost(seen) {
  seen.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block"
}
```

```html
<div class="UPD">
  <button class="collapsible" onclick="lost(this)">button</button>
  <div class="ui-form-element section-row sections" id="uid-3-sections" style="display: none;">This is next sibling to button
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends, but I will suggest using `closest()` to get hold of the parent `<div>` and then `querySelector()` to get the right child element. Advantage:

1. You don't need to be concerned with the order of the siblings.
2. The HTML structure can change or elements can be nested in other elements and it will still work.

I suggest to have an attribute (here a `data-` referring to an id, but it could also be a class name) on the button that controls what sibling should be selected.

```js
document.querySelector('button.collapsible').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let parent = e.target.closest('div.UPD');
  let div = parent.querySelector(`div#${e.target.attributes['data-section'].value}`);
  console.log(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="UPD">
  <button class="collapsible" data-section="uid-3-sections">button</button>
  <div class="ui-form-element section-row sections" id="uid-3-sections" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want next immediate sibling then yes you can use nextElementSibling. But if you have more than one siblings and you want to traverse through the siblings, then you might use jquery siblings method

`$(currentElement).siblings()` and it accepts function if you want to filter the siblings based on some attributes